# Typescript type never although type is declared

Tags: typescript

The Typescript compiler outputs that the secondLastBlock is of type never in the while statement. Does anyone have a clue why this is happing?

(The context is irrelevant. It´s just code to reproduce the error)

Error:

```
Property 'color' does not exist on type 'never'.(2339)
```

```js
export interface IBlock {
    color: string;
}

const testAray: IBlock[] = [
    {
        color: "green"
    },
    {
        color: "red"
    },
    {
        color: "yellow"
    },
    {
        color: "blue"
    }
]

const colors = [
    "green",
    "red",
    "yellow",
    "blue"
]

let secondLastBlock: IBlock | null = null;
let lastBlock: IBlock | null = null;
for (const block of testAray) {
    while (
        block.color === secondLastBlock?.color &&
        block.color === lastBlock?.color
    ) {
        block.color = colors[
                Math.ceil(Math.random() * 4)
        ]
    }

    secondLastBlock = lastBlock;
    lastBlock = block;

}
```

Online Playground: [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQCEAbCbAazgG8AoOeubCUqALjgGcYpkBzAbhoBfGjSZIucVFwCCUTAE92RUhQDaAXTgBeOGroNaDY42bR2AIl5RgwJBYP0hAGkfU3xpi0s2AJg+MXNyMTei9zOAsFYGJSAHcAhiDjENDwtkiAI2IAV2BEpxoNUXFJdI4dPTcrGzsLV2MLP3rq6NiIBIaGC2y8h2KaYmB4DmBxXwAZTC4SMnJlWYo4AB84JBzYyvXYwSH4YmmYRfmCY5W1jeIty8F0aDgAClL4bLm4CHQpYFl5BQBKdzGOIACwQQ0eHgYrwoADp0jptLpRuMpjNVOQAPxwsxQOAAMjxkPo0PI2JYCN0BzRcyx6TcANSJhJZPuunK+lCnIYAFlMDBgXDgGCHrz+TD5EhfBAALYPAEAKjgABY-kS4MVAqJjMiIJLUUd0ZUqQa5oJjMazroSYJhEA)

Comment: TypeScript is "helpfully" using [assignment narrowing](//www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#assignments) to say that `secondLastBlock` is definitely `null` when you first check it, and then getting confused about the implications of that. I'd suggest using a type assertion to widen the initial assignment so it doesn't do that. See [this playground link](//tsplay.dev/wX0M9w). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: I'm surprised it doesn't give that error if you just change the order of expressions in if statement. `block.color === lastBlock?.color && block.color === secondLastBlock?.color`

Comment: ^ It's definitely buggy/weird TS behavior. I haven't found anything in github about it (usually people report this when using `forEach()` callbacks or the like, but this is just a plain old loop) so I might open an issue when I get the time. But the suggested approach in these situations is generally to opt out of assignment narrowing by using a type assertion.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. What i don´t understand ist that if i comment out the last line (lastBlock=block;)  the same error is shown for lastBlock.
The only difference is that lastBlock is assigned to type block which is of type IBlock. So the assignment narrowing seems to interpret that lastBlock can be assigned to IBlock.

Comment: Loops with assignments in them end up undoing the effects of assignment narrowings. Well, usually, since apparently you've found a case where it doesn't.  I think this might just be a bug in TS, so I can't answer the question as you've asked it until someone (me, maybe) files an issue and it gets triaged.

Comment: I just wanted to confirm here that this isn´t just a error in thought. I will create an issue.

Comment: Feel free to make an issue, just try to reduce it to the minimum necessary to reproduce (maybe something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WKXYMw))? And link to this SO question. And make sure to say this is definitely not a duplicate of #9998; there are no closures involved.  Once your issue gets triaged you should post an answer here saying linking to the github issue and explaining what's going on, so future readers can find it.

Comment: sorry for the mess, i could not report the issue on github. I dont use github often, so i forgot to transfer the 2 factor auth to my new smartphone. Please feel free to submit the issue. I have to wait minimum 3 work days for the account retrieval. I am sure that i forget about the issue before then.

Comment: Okay, [ms/TS#57816](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/57816) has been filed. I'll update when it gets triaged.

Comment: Okay, it is a bug in TypeScript. The good news is that it's listed as "Help Wanted", meaning interested community members could implement a PR for it and there's a good chance it would get accepted (note: I am quite unlikely to do this myself). Is that enough for me to write up an acceptable answer here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is considered a bug in TypeScript, as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#57816](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/57816). It doesn't look like a high priority to be fixed, but the good news is that it's listed as [Help Wanted](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/labels/Help%20Wanted), meaning that they would consider accepting a pull request submitted by community members. So if you really want to see this fixed, you might want to try to fix it yourself and get the fix merged into the language.

On the other hand you might just want to work around it. In cases where [assignment narrowing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#assignments) of a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) gets it wrong (there's a whole huge issue at [microsoft/TypeScript#9998](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998) describing situations where TypeScript simply cannot properly anticipate whether a narrowing should or should not be reset), you can "opt out" of it by using a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) instead of a [type annotation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables).  That is, if you turn

```
let secondLastBlock: IBlock | null = null;
```

into

```
let secondLastBlock = null as IBlock | null;
```

then there's no assignment narrowing (since `null as IBlock | null` hides the fact that you're assigning `null`) and your code will start working as-is.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.4.3&ssl=19&ssc=1&pln=20&pc=17#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgSQCEAbCbAazgG8AoOeubCUqALjgGcYpkBzAbhoBfGjSZIucVFwCCUTAE92RUhQDaAXTgBeOGroNaDY42bR2AIl5RgwJBYP0hAGkfU3xpi0s2AJg+MXNyMTei9zOAsFYGJSAHcAhiDjENDwtkiAI2IAV2BEpxoNUXFJdI4dPTcrGzsLV2MLP3rq6NiIBIaGC2y8h2KaYmB4DmBxXwAZTC4SMkpdJBzYuGmCWYo4AB84RdjBIfhiaZh18mVTrZ2l4krd4kF0aDgAClL4bLm4CHQpYFl5BQASncxjiAAsEEMXh4GB8KAA6dI6bS6UbjKYzVTkAD8iLMUDgADJCTD6HDyHiWMjdEdMXNcek3MDUiZyZSnrpyvpQqEALKYGBgxHASHPfmC+HyJC+CAAW2ewIAVHAACyA0lwYqBUTGNEQaUYk5Yyq0o1zQTGU0XXTkwTCIA)